# List assignment out of index

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following program that assigns dictionary keys to an array ( `addr[]` ) and values to a corresponding array ( `msg[]` )

```
import smtplib  

class item:
    id = 0 # next available Item ID
    def __init__(self,startBid,desc):
        self.id = item.id
        item.id += 1
        self.highBid = startBid
        self.highBidder = None
        self.desc = desc
        self.isopen = True

item1 = item(200.30, "bike with a flat tire")
item2 = item(10.4, "toaster that is very large")
item3 = item(40.50, "computer with 8 gb of ram")

clnts = {'test@hotmail.com':[item1,item3], 'test@yahoo.com':[item2] }

def even(num):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getmsg(clnts):
    index = 0
    j = 0
    msg = []
    addr = []

    for key in clnts:
        addr[j] = key
        for key in values:
            msg[j] += str(key.highbidder()) + key.highbid()
            index += 1
            j += 1

getmsg(clnts)
```

I've tried and tried to fix this but I keep getting an error:

```
line 39, in getmsg
    addr[j] = key
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, you cannot assign to an index that does not already exist:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x[0] = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Instead of

```
addr[j] = key
```

Try

```
addr.append(key)
```

You could do away with `j` altogether, because you'll have to do the same with `msg`.

There are some other problems with your code that are not part of your question; I'm assuming these are just errors in trying to make a boiled-down example for a question.

Comment: Good answer.  list.append() is the usual Python way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`addr = []` creates an empty list with no elements.  So addr[0] does not exist, and trying to store anything into the non-existent location will generate an IndexError.  Try `addr.append(key)` instead.

Or instead of using a FORTRAN-style loop with index j, you could use more Pythonic techniques to create and initialize the list in one step:

```
addr = list(clnts.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
def getmsg(clnts):

    msg = []
    addr = []

    for key in clnts:
        addr.append(key)

        for key in values:
            msg.append(str(key.highbidder()) + key.highbid())
```

If you're feeling brave, try [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

---

You'll soon find another problem, however:

```
NameError: global name 'values' is not defined
```

I'm guessing you want the value corresponding to each `key` in clnts:

```
def getmsg(clnts):

    msg = []
    addr = []

    for key in clnts:
        addr.append(key)

        for value in clnts[key]:
            msg.append(str(value.highbidder()) + value.highbid())
```

---

After which you'll find another problem:

```
AttributeError: item instance has no attribute 'highbidder'
```

I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: There are, of course, [more elegant ways of iterating over `clnts`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) but that's beside the point here.